# Using pointer to member function of a base class on object of derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider following code snippet:

```
struct Base {
    std::string foo () const { std::cout << "Base::foo()\n"; return "X"; }
};

struct Der : Base {};

struct Ptr : std::integral_constant<std::string (Base:: *) () const, &Base::foo> {};
```

and usage is like this:

```
Der der;
std::string s = (der.*Ptr::value) ();
std::cout << s << "\n";
```

Output is as desired:

```
Base::foo()
X
```

Everything seems to be fine.

**My question is:** Is this code correct? Or am I stepping on the land of undefined behavior? Can I use pointer to member function of a base class on object of derived class directly?

Comment: I hadn't considered storing pointers in `std::integral_constant` before. That's an interesting approach.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good to hear that part of my question can be useful for others :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, the member belongs to the suboject and thus you must use its type to identify it. Perfectly fine indeed.

The other way around doesn't even compile actually:

```
struct Ptr : std::integral_constant<std::string (Der:: *) () const, &Der::foo> {};
```

The error is pretty clear:

> error: could not convert template argument '&Base::foo' from '[...] (Base::*)() const}' to '[...] (Der::*)() const'

Where I used `[...]` to reduce it a bit.

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly what you posted and that is why the reason of my question about base class :) Anyway thanks